# How do I get the signal from shotgun mic for cameras into audio interface?

Tags: audio-interfaces, cable, shotgun

Want to get the sound from my [Sennheiser MKE 400](https://en-us.sennheiser.com/mke-400) --- a battery-powered shotgun mic with a 3.5 mm TRS output --- into my [Audient Evo 4](https://evo.audio/products/audio-interfaces/evo-4/overview/)'s XLR/TRS combo inputs.

I first tried using a 3.5 mm (1/8") TRS female to 6.35 mm (1/4") TRS male cable, but Evo would not show anything on the meter. I could get some signal if I plugged this 6.35 mm TRS jack into the instrument input on the Evo 4, but it was very noisy.

Reasoning that maybe the Evo 4 interprets only XLR inputs as mics (and TRS inputs as instrument inputs), I then tried chaining the MKE 400 to a 3.5 mm female to 3.5 mm male cable into a 3.5 mm female TRS to XLR male adapter. Same result as before.

I tried both +10 dB and -10 dB settings on the MKE 400.

What's going on here? I was hoping to use the preamps and ADC of the Evo rather than having to rely on the ADC built in to my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I can only make a guess at this, because I cannot find any detailed info on how the mic's pinout is designed.

The interface documentation says the interface's mic jack socket is wired tip hot, ring cold, sleeve ground as a balanced line.
I can guess that the mic is wired to fake a left/right stereo unbalanced signal to a camera, so will be wired tip hot, ring also hot, sleeve ground.
This means that when you plug it into your interface, the polarity on the cold pin is reversed, cancelling the signal out.

I would guess, therefore, that you need a cable with the ring disconnected, to prevent this phase reversal. I'm not sure how common that's going to be. It's the kind of thing I'd just make up myself & label carefully.

Comment: What would happen if I cover the mic's TRS jack's ring with electrical insulation tape? Not sure it would stay on when I insert it into the intermediate cable...

Comment: I imagine you'd be spending some time trying to pull the tape back out of the socket ;) You might get away with something thin like splicing tape, but that's going to be harder to get hold of than 2 plugs & a bit of mono shielded wire, or picking the shielding off a stereo cable & snipping one core..

Comment: Would a 3.5mm TRS Stereo Female to 2x 6.3mm TS mono male Y Splitter Cable work? Like this: https://www.amazon.in/dp/B01JA2RURO .

Comment: I don't know how it would deal with the reverse phase on connecting cold to ground.